# B2C Embedded sign-in experience

Tags: iframe, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

I followed the guide to setup the embedded sign in experience using b2c and an IFrame ([Embedded Sign-In Doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/embedded-login?pivots=b2c-custom-policy)).

However, I am not quite sure on how to get the Access token and use it throughout my Application.
So far I got the IFrame to display the SignIn/SignUp Form and the login/signup works flawless.
But after that the IFrame redirects to the landing page of the application and my "parent" Page does not receive an ID Token.

(The url of the "parent" Page matches the redirect url of the iframe authorization request)

The src of the IFrame is the authorization request url of my b2c policy.

PS: Viewing the network Tab I can see the issued and valid ID Token in the "confirmed" response (redirect-url/#id_token=eyJ0eX...) from the b2c Policy.

Best
Max

Comment: What type of app is this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this why it is indicated in the doc to use window.top.location.reload(); so that the page reloads once login is done and you can capture the id token in your page logic normally.

An example of that is that you can use the following script in your layout:

```html
<!-- Because the authorization flow happens inside the iframe, we need to reload the main page.-->
<script>
    if (document.referrer.startsWith('@Configuration.GetSection("AzureAdB2C")["Instance"]'))
        window.top.location.reload();
</script>
```

Another alternative is that you can set the redirect-url for your login request to a "LoginCompleted" page, and have it do the redirection for you.

Here are a couple of examples of this in action using pre-built samples:

- (.netcore, uses redirect script) https://github.com/helshabini/active-directory-aspnetcore-webapp-openidconnect-v2/tree/master/1-WebApp-OIDC/1-7-B2C-Embedded
- (.net framework, uses login completed page) https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/sign-in-with-iframe
- (nodejs, uses redirect script) https://github.com/techjazz-MS/B2C_EmbeddedSignin_nodejs_passportjs_Sample

Comment: Thank you for your answer!
I used the first example (.netcore) to setup the authentication middelware in ASP.Net Core and I am now able to login via the IFrame.
However, because I am not using Views but instead I use a react app I am not sure on how to pass a Token to the frontend / let the frontend know if the user is authenticated (f.e. to change the Login Button to an Account Button.
Do you have any Idea on how to fix this issue?
Atm. I am getting redirected inside the Iframe.

Comment: So, the react app is completely client side. This should have nothing to do with asp.net core api. The Visual Studio sample simply creates a backend api, with a frontend react app. Therefore, you need configure your react app to authenticate to AADB2C and then issue a token to talk to the backend. Take a look at this: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/tutorial-v2-react
To be clear, this has nothing to do with embedded signin. For embedded signin to work, you just need to refresh the parent page. If you properly set the react state after login things should work.